# Unable to implement MPI_Intercomm_create

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, fortran90, openmpi

I am trying to implement an `MPI_intercomm`  in Fortran between 2 inter communicators, one which has first 2 process and the other having the rest.
I need to perform send, recv operations between the newly created communicators.

The code:

```
program hello
include 'mpif.h'
integer tag,ierr,rank,numtasks,color,new_comm,inter1,inter2

tag = 22
call MPI_Init(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierr)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,numtasks,ierr)

if (rank < 2) then
color = 0
else 
color = 1
end if

call MPI_COMM_SPLIT(MPI_COMM_WORLD,color,rank,new_comm,ierr)

if (color .eq. 0) then

call MPI_INTERCOMM_CREATE(new_comm,0,MPI_Comm_world,1,tag,inter1,ierr)

!local_comm,local leader,peer_comm,remote leader,tag,new,ierr

else if(color .eq. 1) then      
call   MPI_INTERCOMM_CREATE(new_comm,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,0,tag,inter2,ierr)
end if

select case (color)
case (0)
call    MPI_COMM_FREE(inter1)       
case(1)
 call mpi_comm_free(inter2) 

end select

call MPI_finalize(ierr)
end
```

The code compiles without any issues. But gets stuck while running and sometimes shows error.

Comment: What error does it show? Where does it get stuck? What steps have you attempted for debugging?

Comment: For eg if i run with       mpirun -np 8 ./a.out  it just gets stuck as if in an infinite loop. It is not showing any error.

Comment: No effect. Stuck with same bug.

Comment: Tried that ,no results. But I tried several other programs too. All worked fine until I introduced the MPI_INTERCOMM_CREATE function. This single line manages to stop the functioning.  Also would like to know if there is anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. No need to repeat tags in the title.

Comment: Checked those as well to no avail.

Comment: Besides the problem already described in innoSPG's answer, your `MPI_FREE_COMM` calls are missing the error argument. Use one of the modern MPI interfaces, i.e. `use mpi` or `use mpif_08` instead of `include 'mpif.h'` and the compiler will catch most missing arguments problems automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: the problem comes from the specification of the `remote_leader`.

Long answer:
I am assuming that your splitting logic is what you want: process 0 and 1 in color `0` and the rest of the world in color `1`, and also that you will always have more than 3 processes. 
You have to choose:

- the `local_leader` for each color. This is the rank in the local communicator (`new_comm` in your case) of the leader of each group. The headache free approach is to choose the process of rank 0, because this is the rank in the local communicator, all process can have the exact same value. So I am choosing rank 0.
- the `remote_leader` for each color; this must be the rank in the `peer_comm` (`MPI_Comm_world` in your case) of the leader of the other end of the inter-communicator. It means that, process in color 0 have to know what process `0` in color `1` correspond to in `MPI_Comm_world`; and process in colors 1 have to know what process `0` in color `0` correspond to in `MPI_Comm_world`. According to your splitting logic and my logic of choosing the local leader, `remote_leader` must be process `2` for the color 0, and process `0` for color `1`.

And you should be good to go with this modified lines of code:

```
if (color .eq. 0) then
    if(rank==0) print*, ' 0 here'
    call MPI_INTERCOMM_CREATE(new_comm,0,MPI_Comm_world,2,tag,inter1,ierr)

else if(color .eq. 1) then
    if(rank==2) print*, ' 2 here'
    call   MPI_INTERCOMM_CREATE(new_comm,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,0,tag,inter2,ierr)
end if
```

The most important difference with your code is that `remote_leader` is `2` for color `0`. That is the source of the problem.
The secondary difference is that `local_leader` is `0` for color 1. This correspond to my logic of choosing `local_leader`. It is not the source of the problem, however, it can be if you have only `1` process in color `1`.

---

### Update

Thanks to Hristo Iliev, I am adding this update. If your goal was to use process 1 of color 1 as `local_leader`, then the `remote_leader` for color `0` should be `3` and the code will be:

```
if (color .eq. 0) then
    if(rank==0) print*, ' 0 here'
    call MPI_INTERCOMM_CREATE(new_comm,0,MPI_Comm_world,3,tag,inter1,ierr)

else if(color .eq. 1) then
    if(rank==2) print*, ' 2 here'
    call   MPI_INTERCOMM_CREATE(new_comm,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,0,tag,inter2,ierr)
end if
```

Make sure you check everything for this option as I did not pay special attention to check it. Also make sure that you always have more that `1` process in color `1`.

Comment: If `local_leader` of the second group is 1, then the leader of the first group should specify 3 as `remote_leader` (provided that the ranks in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` are used as sorting keys for the split). So, the difference is not secondary.

Comment: @HristoIliev +1 for the great screening, I focus too much on my logic of choosing the process `0` as `local_leader` that I forgot the OP wanted the process `1` as `local_leader` in color 1. updating.

Comment: I would say, the safest option is to always use rank 0 as the local leader.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood the concept. But after adding mpi_send and mpi_recv lines , the  code behaves exactly like before. It even prints the received buffer, but gets stuck as if in an infinite loop.  Please Help.

Comment: Since the original problem is solved, I suggest you asked a new question with the new problem. It keeps your question clear and not confusing for people who are joining the discussion. Make sure you reference this original question in the new question because they share similar code. People will jump in to help and me too. As a good practice, if you are happy with the solution of the original question, accept the answer.