# Send and Receive operations between communicators in MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, openmpi

Following my previous question : [Unable to implement MPI_Intercomm_create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356001/unable-to-implement-mpi-intercomm-create/38360521#38360521)

The problem of MPI_INTERCOMM_CREATE has been solved. But when I try to implement a basic send receive operations between process 0 of color 0 (globally rank = 0) and process 0 of color 1 (ie globally rank = 2), the code just hangs up after printing received buffer.
 the code:

```
program hello
include 'mpif.h'
implicit none 
integer tag,ierr,rank,numtasks,color,new_comm,inter1,inter2
integer sendbuf,recvbuf,tag,stat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)

tag = 22
sendbuf = 222

call MPI_Init(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierr)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,numtasks,ierr)

if (rank < 2) then
color = 0
else 
color = 1
end if

call MPI_COMM_SPLIT(MPI_COMM_WORLD,color,rank,new_comm,ierr)

if (color .eq. 0) then
if (rank == 0) print*,' 0 here'
call MPI_INTERCOMM_CREATE(new_comm,0,MPI_Comm_world,2,tag,inter1,ierr)
call mpi_send(sendbuf,1,MPI_INT,2,tag,inter1,ierr)

!local_comm,local leader,peer_comm,remote leader,tag,new,ierr

else if(color .eq. 1) then
 if(rank ==2) print*,' 2 here'
call MPI_INTERCOMM_CREATE(new_comm,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,0,tag,inter2,ierr)
call mpi_recv(recvbuf,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,inter2,stat,ierr)
print*,recvbuf
end if
end
```

Comment: I just had a very quick glance at the code so it may have more issues, but clearly you have a problem here: `call mpi_recv(recvbuf,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,inter1,stat,ierr)` as this should use `inter2` instead of `inter1`.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. More people will see it. Fortran 90 is just one old version of the language. An advice: In Fortran 90 and newer it is much better to use `use mpi` instead of `include 'mpif.h'`.

Comment: You also don't use `implicit none` (you really should use it!) and you do not declare `stat` anywhere. Either declare it properly as an array or just use `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` instead.

Comment: edit: used inter2 in mpi_recv , declared stat. problem persists.

Comment: And the status? It is not declared above so your code cannot be compiled.

Comment: Even that has been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The communication with intercommunication is not well understood by most users, and examples are not as many as examples for other MPI operations. You can find a good explanation by following [this link](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node143.htm#Node143).

Now, there are two things to remember:

1) Communication in an inter communicator always go from one group to the other group. When sending, the rank of the destination is its the local rank in the remote group communicator. When receiving, the rank of the sender is its local rank in the remote group communicator.

2) Point to point communication (MPI_send and MPI_recv family) is between one sender and one receiver. In your case, everyone in color `0` is sending and everyone in color `1` is receiving, however, if I understood your problem, you want the process `0` of color `0` to send something to the process `0` of color `1`.

The sending code should be something like this:

```
call MPI_COMM_RANK(inter1,irank,ierr)
if(irank==0)then
    call mpi_send(sendbuf,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,inter1,ierr)
end if
```

The receiving code should look like:

```
call MPI_COMM_RANK(inter2,irank,ierr)
if(irank==0)then
    call mpi_recv(recvbuf,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,inter2,stat,ierr)
    print*,'rec buff = ', recvbuf
end if
```

In the sample code, there is a new variable `irank` that I use to query the rank of each process in the inter-communicator; that is the rank of the process in his local communicator. So you will have two process of rank `0`, one for each group, and so on.

It is important to emphasize what other commentators of your post are saying: when building a program in those modern days, use moderns constructs like `use mpi` instead of `include 'mpif.h'` see comment from Vladimir F. Another advise from your previous question was yo use rank `0` as remote leader in both case. If I combine those 2 ideas, your program can look like:

```
program hello
use mpi !instead of include 'mpif.h'
implicit none

    integer :: tag,ierr,rank,numtasks,color,new_comm,inter1,inter2
    integer :: sendbuf,recvbuf,stat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
    integer :: irank
    !
    tag = 22
    sendbuf = 222
    !
    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,numtasks,ierr)
    !
    if (rank < 2) then
        color = 0
    else 
        color = 1
    end if
    !
    call MPI_COMM_SPLIT(MPI_COMM_WORLD,color,rank,new_comm,ierr)
    !
    if (color .eq. 0) then
        call MPI_INTERCOMM_CREATE(new_comm,0,MPI_Comm_world,2,tag,inter1,ierr)
    !
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(inter1,irank,ierr)
    if(irank==0)then
        call mpi_send(sendbuf,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,inter1,ierr)
    end if
    !
    else if(color .eq. 1) then
        call MPI_INTERCOMM_CREATE(new_comm,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,0,tag,inter2,ierr)
        call MPI_COMM_RANK(inter2,irank,ierr)
        if(irank==0)then
            call mpi_recv(recvbuf,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,inter2,stat,ierr)
            if(ierr/=MPI_SUCCESS)print*,'Error in rec '
            print*,'rec buff = ', recvbuf
        end if
    end if
    !
    call MPI_finalize(ierr)
end program h
```